# Jenkins pipeline script - stop previous build, and print message in failed build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, abort

So, I start my pipeline script with this piece of code:

```
node {
if (env.JOB_NAME != 'Company/project/develop' && env.JOB_NAME != 'Company/project/master'){
    def jobName = env.JOB_NAME
    def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

    for (build in job.builds) {
        if (build.isBuilding() && build != job.builds.first()) {
            println '*' * 30
            println 'All previous builds for this job have been aborted!'
            println '*' * 30
            build.doStop()
        }}
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. It stops all previous builds for the same job name. The point of this is to optimize Jenkins when developers are pushing too much code, but latest push is only important one. Master and develop branches are excluded from this rule.

I would like to expand this a little bit, by adding interruption cause. I would like to print into stopped build for example: "This job has been stop because is obsolete..."

I have tried a lot of things posted on stackoverflow, but I didn't succeed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation of similar function. It will abort previous running build, and show cause "Aborted by newer build #123"

```
import hudson.model.Result
import hudson.model.Run
import jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption.UserInterruption

Run previousBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuildInProgress()

while (previousBuild != null) {
    if (previousBuild.isInProgress()) {
        def executor = previousBuild.getExecutor()
        if (executor != null) {
            echo ">> Aborting older build #${previousBuild.number}"
            executor.interrupt(Result.ABORTED, new UserInterruption("Aborted by newer build #${currentBuild.number}"))
        }
    }
    previousBuild = previousBuild.getPreviousBuildInProgress()
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. This code works, but for some reason it doesn't print "Aborted by newer build #123", it prints "Aborted by unknown"...

Comment: @aadlv The correct message will be displayed in Status page, in console output you will only see Aborted by unknown.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getPreviousBuildInProgress`

Comment: ^ That script security exception is something that needs to be resolved by the Jenkins administrator.  They have an admin portal where they can go in and approve potentially dangerous scripts that run in the Jenkins sandbox.